# str_replace for different values

Tags: php, replace

I'm using

```
$grab = str_replace('aa"','bb"', 
            str_replace("a","b",
                str_replace("cc","dd",
                    str_replace("ee","ff",
                        St(getURL("bleep"),"aye",'p')
                    )
                )
            )
        );
```

to automatically change the width. But now random widths are being used and it's not always the same number...

Until recently I could replace `width="720"` and anything inbetween the `" "` got  changed to 640. Now, instead of just when the number is 720, whatever number it has, it should get changed to 640.

Note that it only grabs 1 line of embed code, and the only numbers would be in the width or height attributes.

How can I make the replacement work with varying numbers?

Comment: Parsing HTML like that will never be a stable solution. One day the HTML will have a space after a `=`, or a line break, or will have an unrelated attribute with the value 720 or even 7200. Don't do this. Use a DOM parser like DOMDocument.

Comment: its only set to grab 1 line of embed code the only 720 would be in the width or height as its the only thing with Numbers in the line at all times

Comment: someone said preg_replace but i have no clue about that haha

Comment: What are you trying to do. Show the input and your expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) with the following regular expression:

```
preg_replace('~(width\s*=\s*["\']?)\d+~', '${1}640', $s)
```

... where `$s` is your input string. It will be `GetStringBetween( .....)` in your case.

This regex checks for the presence of `width` followed by optional white space (`\s*`), a literal `=`, again some optional white space, an optional double or single quote (`["\']?`) and then one or more digits (`\d+`). If found, the digits are replaced by 640. The part before it will just be reinstated with `${1}`.

Comment: $grab = str_replace('target="_blank"','target="live"', preg_replace('~(width\s*=\s*["\']?)\d+~', '${1}640', str_replace("480","460", bleh bleh bleh like that?

Comment: Yes, did you try?

Comment: not yet just wanted to make sure it didnt suppose to be separate before i did it haha ill try now

Comment: Works amazingly OMG thanks so much! your a life saver hahaha